# How to sort the array list by subsequent number in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, arraylist

```
ArrayList SortItems = new ArrayList();
        SortItems.Add("Item1");
        SortItems.Add("Item2");
        SortItems.Add("Item3");
        SortItems.Add("Item4");
        SortItems.Add("Item5");
        SortItems.Add("Item6");
        SortItems.Add("Item7");
        SortItems.Add("Item8");
        SortItems.Add("Item9");
        SortItems.Add("Item10");
        SortItems.Add("Item11");

        SortItems.Sort();
```

If i run this program, i will get the below result

[image]

But i want to sort the list like **Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4,Item5,Item6,Item7,Item8,Item9,Item10,Item11**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build custom comparer:

```
public class CusComparer: IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return int.Parse((x as string).Substring(4)) - int.Parse((y as string).Substring(4));
    }
}
```

So you can use:

```
ArrayList SortItems = new ArrayList();
SortItems.Add("Item1");
SortItems.Add("Item2");
SortItems.Add("Item3");
SortItems.Add("Item4");
SortItems.Add("Item5");
SortItems.Add("Item6");
SortItems.Add("Item7");
SortItems.Add("Item8");
SortItems.Add("Item9");
SortItems.Add("Item10");
SortItems.Add("Item11");

SortItems.Sort(new CusComparer());
```

But instead of using `ArrayList`, you should consider using `List<T>` with stronger type

Answer (score 1):

The result is sorted that way because it uses lexicographic ordering on the strings. The comparison algorithm compares two strings from left to right, and since `"1"` is less than `"9"`, `"10"` will be less than `"9"`, too.

You could pad the numeric parts of your strings with zeroes, e.g. `"Item05"` instead of `"Item5"`.

The more generic and flexible way is to use `ArrayList.Sort(IComparer)`, and implement an `IComparer` that understands your string format and can order the strings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not show what kind of result it is giving.

Use SortedList. As and when you add new item, it would be sorted.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx
Downside would be, you cannot have a repetition in the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always prepended with `"Item"`, you can split both and order by the numic part.

Note that i'll use a strongly typed `List<String>` instead:

```
List<String> SortItems = list.Select(s => new
                              {
                                  Item = s, 
                                  Number = int.Parse(s.Substring("Item".Length))
                              }).OrderBy(x => x.Number)
                              .Select(x => x.Item).ToList();
```

or you can use [this `Sort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) overload to sort the original list directly:

```
list.Sort((a, b) =>  
    int.Parse(a.Substring("Item".Length)).CompareTo(int.Parse(b.Substring("Item".Length)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `IComparer` and pass it to the `Sort` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt.aspx